# Name Of the program not seen in Downloads

Tags: eclipse, blackberry, blackberry-simulator

I'm facing a problem in executing the code i've written in eclipse for Blackberry...I cannot see the name of the file in downloads when i tried to execute the eclipse code..To resolve this i went for dese options
1)I've again created another workspace in eclipse and copied that code..
2)Cleaned the project and also bat file

But still im not able to find the name of the file in downloads of Blackberry simulator ..

What might be the reason for it?

Answer (score 1):

1. Does your application class contain `public static main(String[] args)` method?
2. Clean your simulator filesystem (folder) before running your application

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a simulator for an OS6 device, your application will appear on the home screen, not in the downloads folder. Is that the problem?

Comment: noo...all my other programs written are visible..i tried to write another program to see what happens..it is visible..only this program which dont have any sort of errors is not visible..

Comment: when i executed the same program in another system its working

Comment: many times it happened..but when i restarted the eclipse and cleaned the bat file..the file was seen in downloads...